# Do you need to explicitly close connections when using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out if we should be explicitly calling connection.close when using the standard mongoose operations. Under the hood is mongoose & the native driver giving the connection back to the pool when no operations are used on it, or is it calling close behind the scenes, or just letting it timeout before giving it back?

I'm researching as well and will post and answer if I find it.

Answer (score 4):

As [noted here](http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-and-node-js-tutorial/), you should open your mongoose connection once at app startup, and not close it until app shutdown. There's no need to explicitly release the connection in between operations for most applications.